# Issue With DataGridViewComboBoxColumn - Catching Data Errors before DataError event triggers

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a datagridview whihc contains a datagridviewcomboboxcolumn. The data object being bound to the datagrid contains a property whose values are mapped to the datasource values bound to the comboboxcolumn.

My problem is that bad data is occasionally retrieved from the DB, due to which when the datagrid tries to cast the property value to a valid comboboxcolumn value, it throws a data error. I'm unable to catch this in the SET method for the property as well, because it seems on assigning datasource, it doesn't automatically invoke the SET method.

Is there an event I can use to catch this before the data error is thrown? OR any other such workaround that you can think of?

Comment: Isn't DataBindingComplete called before DataError event triggers? I think you can correct your data there when you assign DataSource. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be filter invalid data or correct it, because even if you handle it it means that there will be some inconstancy. Best way is to handle `DataError` it self where you can fix/silence error (I'm not sure if you meant not to handle that event or to happen before it - AFAIK this is the best place in `DataBinding` scenario):

```
private void dgv_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.ThrowException = false;
}
```

Comment: The exception i'm getting is "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid" ..... What I want to do is to convert this erroneous value to a valid value, if possible, else just assign an empty string, which is a valid value in my combobox datasource). The problem with using the DataError event to do this, is that I only want this conversion to be attempted if this error is coming SPECIFICALLY from this combobox in my grid : can I find out which column/value threw the error? If so, I can check if the error is raised on this column, convert the value, and set e.throwexception as false and proceed?

Comment: Only way I can come up with right now is to not use dataginding and creating your own methods for data insertion/updating and validating.